# Codewars Simple Fun #159: Middle Permutation

Tags: python, algorithm

This code is too slow for long strings is there any way to fasten it?

```
from itertools import permutations

def middle_permutation(string):
    q=permutations(string)
    l=[("").join(i) for i in q]
    l.sort()
    if len(l)%2==0:
        return l[int(len(l)/2)-1]
    else:
        return l[int(len(l)/2)-1]
```

I tried a string of about 15 characters and it took too much time.

Comment: `''.join(sorted(permutations(string))[math.factorial(len(string))//2-1])` could be better but still unpratical

Comment: @cards Included in my benchmark, that is about twice as **slow** as the OP's (about 3.2 seconds vs their 1.6 seconds).

Comment: @Kelly Bundy mmm I think it depends on the wb conditions. I tried with `repeat=5, number=100_000` with data `"abcdefg"` and my solution is about 45% faster

Comment: @cards Well, that's a shorter and special case. What is "wb"?

Comment: wb: workbench or bench mark, sorry. I will do some more tests:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're not all on CodeWars here, and that's not what this site is for anyway, so please [edit] the question, i.e. include the details of the challenge (e.g. description, inputs and outputs, constraints) and write a title that summarizes the problem. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This works for me fine and fast:
I am not expert in python but I have little bit knowledge of permutation and combinations, and therefore using that I created this and it worked for me!

```
from math import factorial

def get_nth_permutation(s, n):
    result = []
    available_chars = list(s)
    n -= 1

    for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
        index, n = divmod(n, factorial(i - 1))
        result.append(available_chars.pop(index))

    return ''.join(result)

input_string = "0123456789"
result = get_nth_permutation(input_string, int(factorial(len(input_string))/2))
print(result)
```

Comment: Only works if the input string is sorted.

Comment: And better don't change the program structure, it's supposed to have a `def middle_permutation(string):`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am not as intelligent as you but I just thought that this will help someone

Comment: Doesn't work correctly for length 26, due to the float division.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest brute force I can think of, ~40 times faster than yours for ten letters. Times for three test cases:

```
znkqxoulcw
ozxwuqnlkc 1.5981378555297852 middle_permutation
ozxwuqnlkc 0.03874516487121582 middle_permutation_faster

fqcxdjyigb
gyxqjifdcb 1.6487598419189453 middle_permutation
gyxqjifdcb 0.04453229904174805 middle_permutation_faster

zimtbaxpow
ozxwtpmiba 1.5463643074035645 middle_permutation
ozxwtpmiba 0.035861968994140625 middle_permutation_faster
```

You'll likely need a completely different approach for long strings, but that doesn't sound like the *"fasten [this code]"* you're asking for, it would completely **replace** the code without any resemblance (mine already doesn't look/work much like yours, but it keeps the core aspect of using `itertools.permutations`).

Code:

```py
from itertools import permutations, islice
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc
from time import time
from math import factorial

def middle_permutation(string):
    q=permutations(string)
    l=[("").join(i) for i in q]
    l.sort()
    if len(l)%2==0:
        return l[int(len(l)/2)-1]
    else:
        return l[int(len(l)/2)-1]

def middle_permutation_faster(string):
    return ''.join(next(islice(
        permutations(sorted(string)), 
        factorial(len(string)) // 2 - 1,
        None
    )))

for _ in range(3):
    string = ''.join(sample(abc, 10))
    print(string)
    for f in middle_permutation, middle_permutation_faster:
        t = time()
        print(f(string), time() - t, f.__name__)
    print()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNLasMwEIUufYohUCKB8-2mFHyFXiAUo9qjZIosOZJC27N0k017qF6iV6gU2Y5DCVQrW-955r0344-v9t3vjD4ePw9ezu6_b36kNQ2QR-uNUQ6oaY310KJtDl54MtrlQE5RhdmJaoWu4xeJ50TTqg5x3pLe9ohwFVGpzCvaSjgM7yCeq8T01GDPi8_pthF-199KUXljSagsq1FCQ3WtsBypYqkbf8ggnH0xFtxjJ0gVGzaZ8PmLIc2IgzQWCEjD_inhcxcaskQmCQo1U_x2XRTLVDsei_5gNagNac8SY7Hms1Uqgcrhf7hXrJRSuJD_paOuynSahGt88yyNgQ2dLj0HF1j3RXgOA23I8qSmJ8BiAWuYwSofiI9G4-mFc55lMagyBhUmvkV21wnrplwM0tIKsDDcHFZLnoJsbXQ_nkMsJ2O5vwHk10M5x-pDy7gr3aTOTWTfJu_wYMrnIOdlqUWDZTlWxNPed-vf_wa_)

Answer (score 0):

My timings of this recursive approach indicate reasonable efficiency:

```
def middle_permutation(string):
    s = sorted(string)
    def process():
        nonlocal s
        m = (ls := len(s)) // 2
        if ls % 2:
            return s.pop(m) + process()
        else:       
            return s.pop(m-1) + "".join(reversed(s))
    return process()
```